# Using ASP MVC 6, how do I get a variable set in every page template?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have some extra information about a user that I need to have in every page template (not just the layout). How can get this information, which is a property on my base controller, into every every template?

I've read about making a WebViewPage and setting that as the base view in web.config, but MVC 6 doesn't use a web.config file.

Comment: You could make your layout page also inherit from a base layout too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must to override the `OnActionExecuting` method in your base controller, and set the viewbag data in method body.

ViewBag.UserName = yourObj.UserName;
ViewBag.UserId = yourObj.UserId;

In your template, you just get this data by ViewBag.

Comment: Thanks, Márcio.

It looks like OnActionExecuted gets called after the action. OnActionExecuting gets called before.

For some reason, It won't work for me when I override this. My code is never called. However, it does work if I create a custom filter and override OnActionExecuting.

Answer (score 0):

For real project with a lot of users use [DonutCaching](https://mvcdonutcaching.codeplex.com/) library. So you can render only the template for the user and the rest of the page take from cache. It makes your server faster.

Comment: Thanks! This doesn't solve my immediate problem, but it's a cool tool for the future.

Comment: I believe, it can solve your problem, read the documentation carefully.